# What is the meaning of "the work that went into doing it"?

Tags: meaning, questions

I am applying for the Davidson Fellows Scholarship, which requires for you to write a research paper of remarkable achievement. So here is one of the questions that could be found on the [requirements checklist](https://www.davidsongifted.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/2023_Davidson_Fellows_MATHEMATICS_Requirements.pdf):

> How did you organize the work that went into doing it?

I don't understand the "that went into doing it" part. What do they mean by this?

Comment: "that went into doing it" = "that went into writing the research paper"

Comment: The application **requires you to write**, NOT **for you to write**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metaphorically when you work on a task we say you "put the work into the task".

For this scholarship, you must write an essay, and you must include in the essay information oh how you organised the work that you did when were investigating your subject, writing the formal report and creating the visual model.